# Haskell checking if number is from Fibonacci sequence

Tags: haskell

I'm Haskell beginner. Last time I have learnt about Fibonacci sequences, so I can create Fib sequence. Now I'm wondering how to write a function which checks if number belongs to Fib sequence.

I mean function:

```
belongToFib :: Int -> Bool
```

I don't really need code. Some hints how to handle with this would be enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that really possible, I would start creating the Fibonacci sequence and check against your number (x) as long as the latest Fibonacci number is <= x

Comment: @MatveyAksenov had no idea till now ;s

Comment: If the exercise isn't to search a sequence then you could just check if (5∗n^2+4) or (5∗n^2−4) is a perfect square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you some hints for a solution involving lazy evaluation:

1. Define the list of all fibonacci numbers.
2. Check whether your input number belongs to the sequence.

These are the signatures for the two things you'll need to define:

```
fib :: [Int]
belongToFib :: Int -> Bool
```

Of course you will need some tricks to make this work. Even though your list has a (theoretically) infinite sequence of numbers, if you make sure that you only need to work on a finite subsequence, thanks to its laziness, Haskell will generate only the strictly needed part, and your function will not loop forever. So, when checking for the membership of your number to `fib`, make sure you return `False` at some point.

Another possible solution is to try to find out whether your number is in the fibonacci sequence without actually generating it up to the input, but rather by relying on arithmetic only. As a hint for this, have a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not).

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers) you'll find a number of other ways to check membership to the fibonacci sequence.

**edit**: by the way, beware of overflows with `Int`. You may wish to switch to `Integer` instead.

Comment: For `Int`, when creating the list of Fibonacci numbers, one must beware of overflow.

Comment: I know, I would have suggested to use Integer instead but I decided to keep his original signature. Maybe I'll add it as a side note.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a skeleton of a function that tests if a number occurs in an **increasing** list of numbers:

```
contains _ [] = False
contains n (x:xs) 
   | n == x = True 
   | n < x = ???
   | otherwise = ???
```

Think about what should happen in the cases I left open...

Or, if you are both lazy and allowed to use `Prelude` functions, you may have a look at `dropWhile` instead.